# Best method of bringing over a private project, with massive changes, back to its old public repository (that's already too popular to replace)?

Tags: swift, xcode, git, github, storyboard

I currently have a public repository – my most popular one on GitHub **by far** – that I want to keep as the new active repository. About a month ago, I brought over the public code to a private repository in the hopes of releasing a *different version* of the project with some extra (non-essential) features, as well as a revamped UI.

Unfortunately (and I hate myself for this), I've made so many bug fixes and updates to the code of the private repository (including a structural overhaul of the main-focus feature), that I want it to be the new public repository and stick with that as the single release for now on.

Most of the filenames are still the same, with some minor caveats. There's a graphical UI component to it (Interface Builder Storyboards) that is mostly managed by the IDE (Xcode) – this file I will probably have to replace entirely with the new file version, but that's not a huge issue as Apple discourages users from going in and editing that code directly anyway.

If you're familiar with Xcode and Swift, you'll recognize the IDE below. If not, the project files are listed in the most-left column of each window, with the UI (Storyboard) elements being to the right of that column. Regardless, this is what I'm working with:

[image: New Project vs. Old Project]

As you can see, the Project name is also different (Old: `Ultra for Apple Music` → New: `Themes for Music`).

What would be the best way to bring over the new project? I was thinking of:

1. Creating a new branch on the public repo (not sure what to name it)
2. Copy and pasting most of the code by hand (of the private repo to the public repo)
3. Add the additional Swift files, delete the existing Swift files that are no longer in use on the new version
4. Replace the Storyboard file entirely and reconnect all of the objects in IB manually
5. Merge the new branch with Master

Is there a better way to go about this? Maybe I should just commit directly to Master instead (I know branches are only used for changes on a much smaller-scale). I don't want the project changes on GitHub to appear as if I deleted everything and re-added everything if I don't have to.

Again, I'd rather not have to replace the already-public project page as its already my most popular project on GitHub **by far**.

Comment: Hi. Maybe i don't understand your issue completely but i have done something similar by just deleting old project in Master and copy pasting new one (Had a shitty network library and rewrite it to new structure + inner logic changed)

Comment: To clarify: "I brought over the public code to a private repository" means you copied the contents of the public repository into a new repository? So the new repository has no shared history with the public repository at all (i.e. only a big "initial commit" with the content of the public repo)?